# In Shell how to Replace string from one form to another form

Tags: shell, awk

I have few files which contain a string like `JOY_DOL_XXX` at many places. Which I wanted to replace with another string with double quotes as `"JOY.DOL.XXX"`, but here `XXX` can be anything e.g. `MAN`, `CAT`, `DOG` so in this case I wanted to write a script which replaced this accordingly without specifying it explicitly.

For example:

```
  JOY_DOL_MAN ==> "JOY.DOL.MAN"
  JOY_DOL_CAT ==> "JOY.DOL.CAT"
```

Could you please help me out, how shall I do it.

Comment: Are add **`"`** too  before and after string **?**

Comment: Is XXX always 3 characters? If `JOY_DOL_FOOBAR` appeared in your input, what would the desired output be - `"JOY.DOL.FOO"BAR` or `"JOY.DOL.FOOBAR"` or `JOY_DOL_FOOBAR` or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `awk` may work.

```
awk '{gsub(/_/,".");print "\""$0"\""}' file

awk -F_ '{$1=$1;print "\""$0"\""}' OFS=. file
```

To support more complex request.

```
echo ABC JOY_DOL_CAT XYZ | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if (gsub(/_/,".",$i)) printf "\"%s\" ",$i; else printf "%s ",$i}print ""}'
ABC "JOY.DOL.CAT" XYZ
```

Comment: I have another doubt here,                                          $echo JOY_DOL_XXXX | sed 's|JOY_DOL_\(...\)|"JOY.DOL.\1"|g' 
 Gives me output as "JOY.DOL.XXX"X. But I am expecting "JOY.DO.XXXX" Here XXX may be 3 character or more. Please suggest solution for this

Comment: I found the "awk" solution given above is working fine for this case. Thanks ..

Comment: I have noticed one more issue now. # echo ABC JOY_DOL_CAT XYZ | awk '{gsub(/_/,".");print "\""$0"\""}'                                      
  OUTPUT: "ABC JOY.DOL.CAT XYZ", But I am expecting ABC "JOY.DOL.CAT" XYZ

Comment: This is normal.  When you change request, you get different result.  This may work for your last request, but not other.  `echo ABC JOY_DOL_CAT XYZ | awk '{gsub(/_/,".");print $1,"\""$2"\"",$3}'` If you have another input, create a new post, and add a complete file.

Comment: Added new example in original post.

Answer (score 2):

Sed seems simplest:

```
sed 's|JOY_DOL_\(...\)|"JOY.DOL.\1"|g' file
```

Input:

```
JOY_DOL_MAN
JOY_DOL_CAT
```

Output:

```
"JOY.DOL.MAN"
"JOY.DOL.CAT"
```

- `\(...\)` matches three characters. The are represented in the replacement as `\1`.
- `g` would allow multiple matches to be replaced for every input pattern.

Comment: $ echo JOY_DOL_XXX | sed 's|JOY_DOL_\(...\)|"JOY.DOL.\1"|g'

Comment: By the way you forgot to add slashes to () in your sed command: `echo "JOY_DOL_XXX" | sed 's|JOY_DOL_\(...\)|"JOY.DOL.\1"|g'`. Still those would still work if you enable extended regular expression instead with `-E` or `-r` i.e. `sed -E 's|JOY_DOL_(...)|"JOY.DOL.\1"|g'` or `sed -r 's|JOY_DOL_(...)|"JOY.DOL.\1"|g`. It just depends on the version of sed.